# Is there a quantitative definition of inductive effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect, physical-organic-chemistry

Usually, Inductive effects are compared using the electronegativities and distances. However, this only works in compounds with similar structures. For example, we can predict the following orders of acidity:

$$
\ce{2-fluoropropanoic acid} \underset{K_\mathrm{a}}{\gt} \ce{3-fluoropropanoic acid}\\
\ce{3-fluoropropanoic acid} \underset{K_\mathrm{a}}{\gt} \ce{3-chloropropanoic acid}\\
$$

However, besides these (very valid) qualitative reasonings, I want to know **if there is a *quantitative* way to measure inductive effect.** I am aware that the concept of *group electronegativities* also exists, and that is not what I am referring to.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63273; https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12309

Comment: Maybe the [Hammett](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation#:~:text=The%20Hammett%20equation%20in%20organic,constant%20and%20a%20reaction%20constant.) equation? You can distinguish resonance effects from other effects by comparing substitutions on aromatic vs saturated systems.

Comment: @Karsten the Hammett equation is quite general and does quantitatively describe *combined* inductive, mesomeric, and other effects upon substitution of benzene/benzoic-acid derivatives but does not quantitatively describe inductive effect alone.

Comment: If you use a parent molecule that is not aromatic, you can't have a mesomeric effect. So studying the distinct effect of substituents with different parent molecules does differentiate between mesomeric and inductive effects, e.g. [this paper](https://europepmc.org/backend/ptpmcrender.fcgi?accid=PMC6645133&blobtype=pdf)

Comment: Not an organic chemist myself, can this effects not be accounted for using quantum chemical methods and NBO analysis of the wavefunction?

Answer (score 0):

Since Inductive Effect is a permanent effect involving generation of dipoles within molecules, there could be a way to measure it quantitatively. According to Wikipedia, relative inductive effects can be measured, it is unclear on *how* exactly could it be done.

However, it does mention that inductive effects can be *calculated* through something called the [Hammett equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_equation) that makes relationship between reaction rates and equilibrium constants with respect to substituent (the one due to which inductive effect generates).

Comment: The Hammett equation is quite general and does provide a quantitative description of (combined inductive, mesomeric, and other) substituent effects, but it only works for benzene/benzoic-acid derivatives.